# Adding buttons to JPanel after button click

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

Okay, so I am attempting to make a Flash cards program, and I want it to be that when the Add Set (or new deck of cards) is clicked, it will add a button to represent the set at the bottom of the frame.

What I have now will only show the button after the frame is resized. I don't really know what I'm doing with the panel, as I haven't figured out how to properly lay out all the parts yet.

I need the program to show the set icon in the bottom panel after the set it made.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GraphicsUI extends JPanel {

private DeckList setsList;
CardActions action = new CardActions();

JButton addSetButton, addCardButton;

private JLabel label;
private JPanel bottomPanel;

public GraphicsUI(){
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000,825));
    this.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);




    this.label = new JLabel();
    label.setOpaque(true);
    label.setBackground(Color.white);
    label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));



    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("setIcon.png");       
    //make that set image at bottom



this.addSetButton = new JButton("Add Set");
//      this.addSetButton.setBackground(Color.white);
//      this.addSetButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(240, 180));
        this.add(addSetButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.addSetButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());


    this.addCardButton = new JButton("Add Card");
//  this.addCardButton

    this.add(label);

    JLabel blah = new JLabel();
    blah.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000,30));
    this.add(blah);



    this.bottomPanel = new JPanel();

    this.bottomPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 400));
    this.add(bottomPanel);





}


public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        action.setCommand(CardActions.Command.ADDSET);

        action.setList(getSetInfo());


    }

}

private CardList getSetInfo(){
    CardList cl = new CardList();
    String setName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of your set.");

    if(setName.isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Cannot have an empty set.");
    }

        cl.setSetName(setName);
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("setIcon.png");
        bottomPanel.add(new JButton(img));
            return cl;

}

}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot-link to the images seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've added the button, try calling `revalidate` on the container to update the container hierarchy.

You may also find that the use of `setPreferredSize` may not be leaving enough room for the new button to appear

Answer (score 0):

you should make a new jpanel that contains only buttons that will bring you to the specific set that the user has created. to update the jpanel just call repaint()

Comment: I have a new Jpanel where I want to buttons to go, and I've tried doing the repaint, but  they don't work.

Comment: *"..just call repaint()"*  There is more to it than that.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) for a working example of adding new labels.